# show more than one image in jface tableviewer

Tags: java, swt, jface

I need to show utmost 4 images in a single column of a JFace tableviewer. Using labelprovider i am able to show only a single image.

i have four 16x16 images, based on different conditions i want to show 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 images. Any ideas ?

Until now i have done

```
    private CellLabelProvider getLabelProvider(String id) {
        CellLabelProvider labelProvider = null;
         if(id.equals("PROPERTIES")){
            labelProvider = new ColumnLabelProvider() {

                @Override
            public String getText(Object element) {
                        return null;
                    }

             @Override
            public Image getImage(Object element) {
                 RouteType route=(RouteType) element;
                 if(cond1) return Image1;
                 if (cond2) return Image2;
                             if(cond3) return Image3;
                             if(cond4) return Image4;


                 return null;
            }

            };
            }

}
```

If cond1, cond2, cond3 and cond4 are true i want to return all the four images Image1, Image2, Image3 and Image4.

Answer (score 1):

As you have seen the label provider only supports one image.

You might be able to use a class derived from `org.eclipse.jface.resource.CompositeImageDescriptor` to combine multiple images in to a single image. I am not sure how well the table will deal with varying width images.

If that does not work you can use a label provider derived from `org.eclipse.jface.viewers.OwnerDrawLabelProvider`. This label provider gives you complete control over drawing the table cells, but requires some experience with SWT `GC` drawing operations.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically creating one composite image might be another solution if you would like to stick at your label provider. I would like to share it, though I didn't try it.

`// inside your getImage method
        // say you have three images to show
        Image compositeImg = new Image(Display.getCurrent(), 48, 16);
        GC gc = new GC(compositeImg);
        gc.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);
        gc.drawImage(img2, 16, 0);
        gc.drawImage(img3, 32, 0);
        gc.dispose();
        return compositeImg;`

`img1`, `img2`, and `img3` are your `Image` instances created before with size of 16x16 pixels. You can easily structure them into your algorithm to correctly create the composite.

In case of a misbehaving table with a varying width of images as @greg-449 pointed, you may choose your composite's width of fixed size of 16x4 = 64.